# Is the equivalence class of $\Theta()$ or $\sim$ totally ordered

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, computer-science

So, [big O](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is a partial order on functions(from natural numbers to positive reals), and big $\Theta$ forms an equivalence class, are these equivalence classes/partitions totally ordered by big O (or little o)?

Can this be done generally for equivalence classes defined by a partial order in this way ($a\sim b \iff a \leq b \wedge b \leq a$)

Comment: Technically, big O is not a partial order, because $f=O( g)$ and $g=O(f)$ does not mean $f=g.$ So big O is a preorder.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. I imagine the equivalence classes form a partial order though? as its actually antisymetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting order is not a total order, unfortunately. For example, note that the class $\Theta(1)$ are precisely those which are bounded above and also bounded away from zero. Hence, this class is incomparable with $\Theta(n|\!\sin(n)|)$.

(I think the answer still remains no if one restricts to only the classes which containing a nondecreasing function, by doing something like a step function where the steps get exponentially longer
and comparing this with $\Theta(\log(n))$, but I haven't worked through the details.)

In general, if one starts with a partial order and produces such an order on the equivalence classes, it will be isomorphic to the original. Hence, this construction can give arbitrarily "bad" (non-total) orders. This does not hold in the $O$/$\Theta$ case because, as Thomas Andrews points out, $O$ defines only a preorder on  nonnegative functions.